# Batch File - find a string which includes a carriage return and text and replace with something else.

Tags: batch-file, replace

I am struggling with a batch file whereby I want to remove a line break. Specifically I only want to remove line breaks in certain circumstances. 
I have a text file with the below format:

```
TOTAL, blah1, blah2, blah3
PART, blah1, blah2, blah3
PART, blah1, blah2, blah3
TOTAL, blah1, blah2, blah3
PART, blah1, blah2, blah3
TOTAL, blah1, blah2, blah3
PART, blah1, blah2, blah3
PART, blah1, blah2, blah3
```

The output I desire is:

```
TOTAL, blah1, blah2, blah3 PART, blah1, blah2, blah3 PART, blah1, blah2, blah3
TOTAL, blah1, blah2, blah3 PART, blah1, blah2, blah3
TOTAL, blah1, blah2, blah3 PART, blah1, blah2, blah3 PART, blah1, blah2, blah3
```

In summary I want all "PART" records to appear in the same line as the TOTAL record above them.
I can achieve this in a Text Editor with find/replace, by finding a line break followed by the string "PART" and replace this with a space character. 
I need to automate this procedure with a batch file, as I will have around 80 *.txt files in a folder that this should be ran against. 
Ideally the batch file should create a renamed copy of the original file, leaving the original unedited.

All I have managed to find thus far is how to remove ALL line breaks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Check out [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044), a pure script based regular expression text processing utility.  A simple solution is `call jrepl "\r?\n(?=PART)" " " /m /f test.txt /o test.new.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=c:\106x"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR %%a IN (%sourcedir%\*.txt) DO (
(
 SET "line="
  FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%p IN (%%a) DO (
   IF "%%p"=="TOTAL," (
    IF DEFINED line ECHO !line:~1!  
    SET "line="
   )
   SET "line=!line! %%p %%q"
  )
  IF DEFINED line ECHO !line:~1!
 )
)>"%destdir%\%%~na.new" 
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances and change the filemask `*.txt` to suit.

For each file in the source directory matching `*.txt`, read each line. If the line begins "TOTAL," then output any accumulated line in `line` and clear `line`, then accumulate the text into `line`.

The destination filename would be in the destination directory, same name as the original (`%~na`) and extension `.new`

Comment: Thank you - this has worked perfectly. My initial code looked similar but it appears I was struggling with the section:  IF "%%p"=="TOTAL," (
    IF DEFINED line ECHO !line:~1!  
    SET "line="
   )